# Highcharts - Hidden charts don't get re-size properly

Tags: highcharts, susy-compass

I currently have a 3 tabbed page. Each tab is a div that is set to `display: hidden` when not selected. In these tabs I have a Grid system created with Susy (compass plugin). Also each tab  page has a set of Highcharts. When I load the page, depending on which tab is in the URl, one of the tabs is loaded. All of the charts look fine, however when I switch to a different tab, some of the charts are not fitting correctly in their div. If I just re-size the window, the charts are recalculated and then they fit perfectly. Or if I reload that same tab, the charts fit fine too. **Can I call a function that will resize all the charts on the page when I make my tab switch?**

It looks like this: 
[image: How it looks]

when it should look like this: 
[image: How it should look]

EDIT:
Seems like this isn't a problem directly related to highcharts, for example my google maps looks like this: 
[image: How Google Maps looks]

but when I resize the window it adjusts correctly: 
[image: How Google Maps looks after resize]

Can I make CSS refresh/adjust my grids through a function call in JS when the tab gets switched?

Comment: It's really hard to know without seeing more code, but I would guess that something is setting "width" and "height" directly on the charts - probably highcharts JS. On option is for JS to change those values - but you should be able to override the width setting with `max-width: 100%` - as you might with images in a responsive grid.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

What worked for me is calling:

```
$(window).resize();
```

When I load a new tab. Still having the issues with the Google Maps API, but it works great with Highcharts.

Comment: To save someone a couple of minutes here is the full snippet for jQuery UI / Tabs and the Highcharts-Width-Problem. 

          $(function () {
              $("#tabs").tabs(
                  {
                      activate: function () {
                          $(window).resize();
                      }
                  });
          });

Comment: window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize')) is less jQuery code

Comment: `new Event('resize')` is elegant, but unfortunately unsupported by IE. For cross-browser support use 
`var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent("resize", false, true); 
window.dispatchEvent(evt);`

Comment: google.maps.event.trigger(MapObject, 'resize');, call this when moving to tab with Google Maps will fix the Google Map issue. var MapObject = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('#myMap'), { });

Answer (score 6):

You will find a lot of issues when you are trying to render things that start off using "display: none". While $(window).resize() might work in many cases, I would suggest trying to first render your page before having display: none take effect. A possible solution would be to set opacity: 0 or visibility: hidden.

The display attribute is what controls how your element will render, for instance block (100% width) or inline (fit contents). When an element has display: none, it overrides this, ultimately removing it's effective width and height until that element receives a block type.

Here is a example to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/m2f3scmm/3/

```
<div id="log1" style="display: none;">
</div>
<div id="log2" style="visibility: hidden;">
</div>
<div id="log3" style="opacity: 0">
</div>
```

When you are using the "resize" hack, you are assuming the plugin or script you are using is binding to the window's resize event which is not always the case. Triggering the window.resize could also slow down rendering or cause unwanted effects (for instance, the little animation highcharts does when first rendering - which looks lame when it happens each time a tab is changed).

Answer (score 3):

```
/**
 * Adjust size for hidden charts
 * @param chart highcharts
 */
function adjustGraph(chart) {
    try {
        if (typeof (chart === 'undefined' || chart === null) && this instanceof jQuery) { // if no obj chart and the context is set
            this.find('.chart-container:visible').each(function () { // for only visible charts container in the curent context
                $container = $(this); // context container
                $container.find('div[id^="chart-"]').each(function () { // for only chart
                    $chart = $(this).highcharts(); // cast from JQuery to highcharts obj
                    $chart.setSize($container.width(), $chart.chartHeight, doAnimation = true); // adjust chart size with animation transition
                });
            });
        } else {
            chart.setSize($('.chart-container:visible').width(), chart.chartHeight, doAnimation = true); // if chart is set, adjust
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

## **usage**

```
$(window).resize(function () {
        if (this.resizeTO) clearTimeout(this.resizeTO);
        this.resizeTO = setTimeout(function () {
            // resizeEnd call function with pass context body
            adjustGraph.call($('body'));

        }, 500);
    });
```

**for bootstrap tab**

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
            var isChart = $(this).attr('data-chart');
            var target = $(this).attr('href');
            if (isChart) {
                // call functio inside context target
                adjustGraph.call($(target));
            }
        });



  <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#anagrafica" data-toggle="tab"><h5>Anagrafica</h5></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#consumi" data-toggle="tab" data-chart="1"><h5>Consumi</h5></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

**on chart**

```
new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'chart-bar',
                defaultSeriesType: 'column',
                zoomType: 'xy',
                backgroundColor: null,
                events: {
                    load: function (event) {
                        adjustGraph(this);
                    }
                }
            },
```

**html code**

```
div class="tab-pane" id="charts">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6 offset3">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                <!-- Carousel items -->
                <div class="carousel-inner chart-container">
                    <div class="active item">
                        <h3>Chart 1/h3>
                        <div id="bar-pod-annuale">
                           <div id="chart-bar" style="width:100%;margin: 0 auto"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h3>Char 2</h3>
                        /** chart **/
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h3>Char 3</h3>
                        /** chart **/
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Carousel nav -->
                <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
                <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**See on jsfiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/davide_vallicella/LuxFd/2/