# Highcharts won't fit in Bootstrap 3 modal body

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I fit and make a highcharts chart responsive with Bootstrap 3 modals? It seems that the chart is independent from the css of the page, but I'm not sure.

[image: highcharts modal]

```
<div class="modal fade" id="chart-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Assortment Analysis</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="container"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```javascript
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked column chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Lazada', 'Competitor 1', 'Competitor 2', 'Competitor 3', 'Competitor 4']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Price Range'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.percentage:.0f}%)<br/>',
            shared: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'percent'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: '100 - 300',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
        }, {
            name: '301 - 500',
            data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
        }, {
            name: '501 - 1000',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
        }, {
            name: '1001 - 3000',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
        }, {
            name: '3001 - 5000',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
        }, {
            name: '5001 - 10000',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
        }]
    });
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e76933uv/).

Reflow fix:

```
$('#reflow-chart').click(function () {
    $('#first-chart').highcharts().reflow();
    $('#second-chart').highcharts().reflow();
});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a [common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216722/highcharts-hidden-charts-dont-get-re-size-properly) issue with highcharts. The best advice I could get is to use `window.resize()` after Highcharts is shown, but actually there is an API function in Highcharts called [`reflow`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.reflow), that could also help.

The solution is to catch bootstrap modal events and update your Highcharts width in callback of [shown.bs.modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) event:

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
$('#chart-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
    $('#container').css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
$('#chart-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $('#container').css('visibility', 'initial');
    chart.reflow();
});
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e76933uv/3/). I use `visibility` css property here so Highchart won't bounce. This is not ideal, but better than nothing.

Comment: Have you come across another way to avoid the jump at the end?

Comment: @Notflip, I don't use hightcharts myself, unfortunately. But you could ask a new question, maybe there is a better way.

Comment: I fixed it by changing the modal fade to no fade, so it just pops up. It's less smooth but the jump isn't there

Comment: Is there a plain javascript way to do this?

Comment: I had an issue where the height would expand indefinitely and added a bit of code in the resize event to address it, based on your solution.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/41582333/350270

Answer (score 2):

I tried the accepted solution, but in my case I didn't have an option to use a specific module id that already exist in the html, so solution below didn't work for me.

```
$('<modal-id>').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
   chart.reflow();
});
```

What I was trying to do is, dynamically adding a modal to the html as an EmberJS component which only has a specific class.

My solution was this:

```
App.registerComponentFactory('my-chart', SplineChart.extend({
    setup: (function() {
      $('body')
      .off('shown.bs.modal', '.my-modal')
      .on('shown.bs.modal', '.my-modal', () => this.reflow());
}).on('init'),
```

So each time my chart module is initialized, it binds the event handler to the modal.
And the

```
.off('shown.bs.modal', '.my-modal')
```

part is also needed for unbinding the handler each time when the modal is triggered, otherwise the reflow function was running successfully only in the first attempt.

This may be useful for similar cases.

Answer (score 0):

Apply this

```
chart: {
 events: {
            load: function(chart) {
                 $timeout(function() {
                      chart.target.reflow();   
                 );
          }
      }};
```

Answer (score 0):

for responsive highcharts with modal on bootstrap 3 just adding this line code on load page

```
$('#yourmodal').on('off.bs.modal', function() {
    $('#yourselector').css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
$('#yourmodal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $('#yourselector').css('visibility', 'initial');
    $('#yourselector').highcharts().reflow();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#J_report_graph').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
                            $("#J_report_graph_container").highcharts({});
                        });

$("#J_report_graph").modal();
```

will work as expected