# Highcharts width flow out of parent div

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, angular-material

I am trying to create a dashboard where I want a chart made using `highcharts` and an action box in a `row` and in turn two buttons in action box in `column`. I want the action box to wrap the content and chart to take leftover space. But I am not getting expected result. The `chart` is taking more width than its `parent div` i.e. its `container`. Here is my HTML code.

```
<md-content flex layout-padding>
    <md-card layout="row" layout-wrap>
        <div flex layout-padding>
            <highchart id="summary-chart" config="dashboard.chartConfig"></highchart>
        </div>
        <div layout-align="start center" layout="column" layout-padding>
            <div layout-align="start center" layout-fill>
                <img src="../../../assets/images/computer.png">
                <label layout-fill>Computer</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </md-card>
</md-content>
```

Here is something that I expect: 
[image]

This is what I am getting as result:
[image]

**Note: The icon is hidden by the chart**

Comment: I think that your problem may be connected with these SO topics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206631/why-are-bootstrap-tabs-displaying-tab-pane-divs-with-incorrect-widths-when-using and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398127/highcharts-wont-fit-in-bootstrap-3-modal-body

Comment: Thanks. This seems like the solution. But chart.reflow() doesn't work straightaway. I am trying to find a work around. And I can not fix the width of the chart as I need to make them responsive.

Answer (score 0):

To keep your chart from pushing outside its boundaries while maintaining your responsive layout, I would suggest the following.

First, give the flex div element that contains your Highcharts visualization its own ID (in this example, `chartContainer`):

```
<md-content flex layout-padding>
    <md-card layout="row" layout-wrap>
        <div flex layout-padding id="chartContainer">
            <highchart id="summary-chart" config="dashboard.chartConfig"></highchart>
        </div>
        <div layout-align="start center" layout="column" layout-padding>
            <div layout-align="start center" layout-fill>
                <img src="../../../assets/images/computer.png">
                <label layout-fill>Computer</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </md-card>
</md-content>
```

Next, whenever `chartContainer` div is resized, set the size of the `highchart` element to match the width and height of that div:

```
$(".chartContainer").resize(function () {
    $('#summary-chart').highcharts().setSize(
        $(".chartContainer").width(), // new width of the containing div
        $(".chartContainer").height(), // new height of the containing div
        false // don't animate the chart itself changing
    );
});
```

Please note that I'm making an assumption that the `highcharts` element can be passed values using `setSize()` as with standard div elements.

Let me know whether this is helpful for you.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. The chart becomes very small. Tested it and inspecting element show, `chartContainer` is of correct size, `summary-chart` is of correct size `highchairs-container` is of correct size, but there is a `<svg/>` which is small and of fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your css file

```
 .highcharts-container {
    width:100% !important;
    height:100% !important;
 }
```